# What do the X and Y axis stand for in the Fourier Transformation in wolfram mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fft, axis

In wolfram mathematica the function Fourier has the following declaration

```
Fourier[list]
```

And after a list is given to the function, a simple ListLinePlot gives the following result: [image: Graphic]

My question is: What do the X and Y axis represent in this result?

Comment: Probably you will get more response at the [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[GaussianFilter[list, 10]] where list is list of doubles. @Kuba I belive that the X axis is for the time ?

Comment: No, you have provided 2D matrix so you've got FFT in two directions: `ArrayPlot@Abs@Fourier@RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]`

Answer (score 1):

The frequency spectrum is from 0 to fs, where fs is your sampling frequency.So in response to your question the Y-axis is the amplitude (because you took the ABS value of the complex output) and the X-axis is the frequency values from 0 to fs.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, went to the mathematica site and saw the line you just quoted.Changed post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica, Fourier[list] returns the values of the Fourier transform, and does mot give you the grid on which he calculates it. So in your plot the X axis is just the place of the element in the list.

To get the frequencies from the values of X, you basically have to multiply these vales by `2*pi/size` where size is the size of your time interval.